# ActiveMQ - getting ORA-01465: invalid hex number while trying to enqueue a message

Tags: java, oracle, jms, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I have an app, it was running (almost) ok in tomee+ 1.5.2 (activemq 5.7.0)

Now, with tomee+ 1.6.0 (activemq 5.9.0), when I try to enqueue a message, I am getting ORA-01465

Nov 21, 2013 12:30:17 PM org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter log
WARNING: Commit failed: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
, due to: ORA-01465: invalid hex number

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
>
> ```
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeForRowsWithTimeout(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10932)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11043)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:244)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.executeBatch(TransactionContext.java:106)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.executeBatch(TransactionContext.java:84)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.commit(TransactionContext.java:171)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.commitTransaction(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:516)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.prepare(JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java:84)
> at org.apache.activemq.transaction.XATransaction.prepare(XATransaction.java:192)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.prepareTransaction(TransactionBroker.java:248)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.prepareTransaction(MutableBrokerFilter.java:127)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processPrepareTransaction(TransportConnection.java:405)
> at org.apache.activemq.command.TransactionInfo.visit(TransactionInfo.java:98)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
> ```
>
> Nov 21, 2013 12:30:17 PM org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext
>   prepare WARNING: prepare of:
>   XID:[1197822575,globalId=19000000047544d4944000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,branchId=2000000047544d4944000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
>   failed with: javax.jms.JMSException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
>
> javax.jms.JMSException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
>
> ```
> at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
> at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1405)
> at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.syncSendPacketWithInterruptionHandling(TransactionContext.java:757)
> at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.prepare(TransactionContext.java:453)
> at org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction.prepare(LocalAndXATransaction.java:120)
> at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.WrapperNamedXAResource.prepare(WrapperNamedXAResource.java:86)
> at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.internalPrepare(TransactionImpl.java:429)
> at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:312)
> at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:328)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:75)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:76)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:231)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:272)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:267)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:90)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:306)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
> at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
> at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
> at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
> at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:68)
> at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
> at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1601)
> at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1041)
> at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:289)
> at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1415)
> at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:765)
> at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
> at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
> at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
> at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
> at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: java.io.IOException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
>
> at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:45)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.commit(TransactionContext.java:180)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.commitTransaction(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:516)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.prepare(JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java:84)
> at org.apache.activemq.transaction.XATransaction.prepare(XATransaction.java:192)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.prepareTransaction(TransactionBroker.java:248)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.prepareTransaction(MutableBrokerFilter.java:127)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processPrepareTransaction(TransportConnection.java:405)
> at org.apache.activemq.command.TransactionInfo.visit(TransactionInfo.java:98)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
> at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
> at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
> ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11190)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:244)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.executeBatch(TransactionContext.java:106)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.executeBatch(TransactionContext.java:84)
> at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.commit(TransactionContext.java:171)
> ... 16 more
> ```

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the ActiveMQ 5.9 migration guide.
http://activemq.apache.org/59-migration-guide.html

It lists a change related to JDBC persistence adapters about a column type change.